# scheduleAtFixedRate method of ScheduledExecutor calls only one thread out of 2 threads created

Tags: java, multithreading

This is in continuation with one of my older questions. I want to execute a program based on two conditions, N inserts in a database and time interval. I got two brilliant answers as well. This is one of them, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26043250/1930402).

I implemented the solution in similar lines. So, I expected the program to run according to both threads -A run because of database check at every single minute and time based run at every 5 minutes. But I am seeing only time based running happens every 5 minutes and database checking is happening just once.

Could you please advise what causes this.

Comment: @Jean Logeart-Could you please help out.

Comment: @Will Hartung : Could you please help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone who thought of helping out!

Here the issue was this- I was making use of another class to check database inserts. The object of this class was created in the constructor of this listener class, that is only once. I think for every thread this requires to be recreated. Once I did this, it started working well.