# NoSuchMethod Error in Java-Solved: Multiple projects added in POM.xml as dependencies had same class name and same method. Renamed them

Tags: java, maven

I have a listener program that triggers a main program based on the below  conditions

1. If the database has new records
2. If the time from last run is 10 minutes.

This is  done using `ScheduledExecutorService` of Java (https://stackoverflow.com/a/26043250/1930402 helped out).
So, I am calling a perfectly working program from this Listener, located in another Project and another Folder. That is, I am calling project B from project A.  To enable this, I added a dependency of Project B in Project A's `POM.xml`.

There is an error in one of the classes of Project B, and it is `NoSuchMethodError`. I can see the method right there. From the answers of this post, https://stackoverflow.com/a/24902026/1930402, I understand that this particular class might not be there in my build path. I am not sure of this.

Can anyone advise?

Note: Project B runs without any issues when it is run independently.

Java Doc tells:

> "Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed."

How can the definition of my class change while running using a static instance?

This is my stack:

```
         java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:a.b.c.StringUtils.formatDateToString(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

So, these are the key points: Maven Dependency, `ScheduledExecutorService`, Static Class.

Comment: You probably have old version of class. Try rebuild you app.

Comment: Really is that method there? The same parameter types? static/non-static and such.

Comment: @talex - Maven clean, update and install -> done for both projects

Comment: @JoopEggen: Yes. Method is there, same parameter types, but static. Calling with the class name.

Comment: Post stack. Maybe it helps to understand your problem

Comment: @talex: I am sorry, cannot paste full stack. This is the error line. Others just point to the classes.

Comment: If you turn off obfuscation problem still exists?

Comment: have you deleted jar with project B from m2 folder?

Comment: That time, error won't be seen. Program doesn't give output.

Comment: No, I didn't delete the jar with Project B from m2. Should I try that oncce?

Comment: You might look in the jar too, for instance renaming a copy to .zip. Then write some code to inspect the class: getProtectionDomain().getLocation(); getDeclaredMethods(). That tip with the maven repository is crucial.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error was that same class names and same package names were present in Project A and Project B and a set of other projects which were being used. Once I made each of them unique, things started working fine.